# Angular tests: way to test files

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Is there any way to test a group of files in angular? like using flags?
In my case, I make a service test file (service.spec.ts) to do an integration test with my api. In this test the angular service send a real XHR requests. But I don't want to execute that files every time I test other components. Any suggestions?
My intent:
the usual:
    `ng test`

when test sever:
    `ne test -flag-that-allow-just-to-test-real-services`

Comment: To start, your unit tests should *never* send actual requests to your back end.  You should be able to run front end unit tests without relying on your back end to be running.  You want to create mock services that can 'fake' the response from an API request.  Additionally, if you wanted to only test one test in particular and not the entire group, you can add `f` in front of your it or your describe: `fit()` or `fdescribe` and `ng test` will only run those groups tests

Comment: You might want to start here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

Comment: @Rinktacular then, how can I check if the request URL is the correct one? How can I test that?